# Partition of Timestamp column in Dataframes Pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, dataframe, timestamp, pyspark, partition

I have a `DataFrame` in PSspark in the below format

```
Date        Id  Name    Hours   Dno Dname
12/11/2013  1   sam     8       102 It
12/10/2013  2   Ram     7       102 It
11/10/2013  3   Jack    8       103 Accounts
12/11/2013  4   Jim     9       101 Marketing
```

I want to do partition based on `dno` and save as table in Hive using Parquet format.

```py
df.write.saveAsTable(
    'default.testing', mode='overwrite', partitionBy='Dno', format='parquet')
```

The query worked fine and  created table in Hive with Parquet input.

Now I want to do partitioned based on the year and month of the date column. The timestamp is Unix timestamp

how can we achieve that in PySpark. I have done it in hive but unable to do it PySpark

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**Spark >= 3.1**

Instead of `cast` use `timestamp_seconds`

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import timestamp_seconds

year(timestamp_seconds(col("timestamp")))
```

**Spark < 3.1**

Just extract fields you want to use and provide a list of columns as an argument to the `partitionBy` of the writer. If `timestamp` is UNIX timestamps expressed in seconds:

```py
df = sc.parallelize([
    (1484810378, 1, "sam", 8, 102, "It"),
    (1484815300, 2, "ram", 7, 103, "Accounts")
]).toDF(["timestamp", "id", "name", "hours", "dno", "dname"])
```

add columns:

```py
from pyspark.sql.functions import year, month, col

df_with_year_and_month = (df
    .withColumn("year", year(col("timestamp").cast("timestamp")))
    .withColumn("month", month(col("timestamp").cast("timestamp"))))
```

and write:

```py
(df_with_year_and_month
    .write
    .partitionBy("year", "month")
    .mode("overwrite")
    .format("parquet")
    .saveAsTable("default.testing"))
```

Comment: I tried your technique to partition by hour and then write to parquet: df.write.partitionBy('hour').parquet(path) , however, despite having at least 10 unique hours in the df, I'm getting only 2 parts of parquet - can you help explaining that? Thanks!

Comment: @Davos Not really a trick, but [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) recommendation "The preferred way of wrapping long lines is by using Python's implied line continuation inside parentheses, brackets and braces. Long lines can be broken over multiple lines by wrapping expressions in parentheses. These should be used in preference to using a backslash for line continuation."